# Help me set constant current to 1.5mA output and LED to 20mA

Tags: led, constant-current

I don't understand enough to accomplish this, constant current output to 1.5mA LED current to 20mA its simply been too long since I learned these things. Im only modifying an existing (likely popular) circuit.

[image: Circuit]

Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: I tried modifying R7 from 2 - 2k ohms yet current did not increase past 8mA.

Comment: Lower R6 to 100K. You might not have enough current at the base to amplify.

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.